# edit values in SQL table based on condition on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 2 tables.

The first table is called `USER_CARD_MANAGEMENT` and has 2 columns: `card_ID`, `User_ID`.

The second table is called `USER_MANAGEMENT` and has 3 columns: `user_ID`, `USER_Name`, `Domain`.

We have some records in the 2nd tables where user_name is duplicated for 2 different domains (root domain, child domain ).

We need to Replace the `user_ID` if it belongs to a child domain to match  `user_ID` (Root domain) then delete the record for the child domain from 2nd table.

Sample data:

```
USER_CARD_MANAGEMENT 
 UserID  CARd_id
      1  5566889
      6  6575900
     11  5678809
     26  4335679

USER_MANAGEMENT
UserID  USER_NAME    Domain
     1  mike.smith   child
     2  mike.smith   root
     3  Dina.tom     root 
     4  hala.viktor  root
    11  Nada.peter   child
    12  nada.peter   root
```

simply i need to edit the ID in 1st column if we have a duplicate user_name in 2nd table to match user_id that has domain =root

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.) The answer may depend on the dbms used...

Comment: First you should decide what database you are using and tag the question appropriately.  You should also edit the question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a fairly straight forward query if I'm reading it right.

Comment: [Abeer Mohamed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5065141/abeer-mohamed) what you mean by "We need to Replace the user_ID if it belongs to a child domain to match  user_ID"

Comment: am using SQL but am not developer so am not sure if this is correct

Comment: update [AAM].[dbo].[USERCARDMANAGEMENT] [USER_ID]
set [USER_ID] =
(select USER_ID
from [AAM].[dbo].[USERMANAGEMENT]
where CATEGORY='vodafone-de-ldap' AND count(USER_NAME)>1)
inner join [AAM].[dbo].[USERMANAGEMENT]
ON [AAM].[dbo].[USERMANAGEMENT]. USER_ID =[AAM].[dbo].[USERCARDMANAGEMENT]. USER_ID
WHERE USER_NAME

Comment: User ID           CARd_id
1                  5566889
6                  6575900
11                  5678809
26                  4335679

User ID            USER_NAME        Domain
1                  mike.smith       child
2                  mike.smith       root
3                  Dina.tom         root
4                  hala.viktor      root
11                  Nada.peter      child
12                  nada.peter      root
simply i need to edit the ID in 1st column if we have dupliate user_name in 2nd table to match user_id that has domain =root

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can be sure that no two users have the same name, try:

```
    UPDATE ucm
       SET User_Id = COALESCE(um2.User_id, um.User_id) FROM user_card_management ucm
      JOIN user_management       um  ON ucm.user_id = um.user_id
 LEFT JOIN user_management      um2  ON um2.user_name = um.user_name
                                    AND um.domain = 'child'
                                    AND um2.domain = 'root'
```